# Unexpected String Translation from Dictionary

Tags: python, string, translate

I'd like to write a program that reads in a file and translates a short string of text 4 characters long to a new string of 4 characters. Currently, I read in a tab-delimited text file containing two columns: an "old tag" and a "new tag". I'm able to successfully build a dictionary that maps the "old tag" as the key and the "new tag" as the value.

My problem comes in when I attempt to use `maketrans()` and `str.translate()`. Somehow my "old_tag" is getting converted to a "new_tag" that I don't even **have** in my dictionary! I've attached screenshots of what I mean.

["P020" should get converted to "AGAC" as outline in my dictionary.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLa5F.png)

[The error is that variable "old_tag" **should** get converted to "AGAC" as outlined in my dictionary, but it's instead getting converted to "ACAC" (look at variable "new_tag"). I don't even **have** ACAC in my translation table!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5xd2.png)

Here's my function that does the string translate:

```
def translate_tag(f_in, old_tag, trn_dict):
"""Function to convert any old tags to their new format based on the translation dictionary (variable "trn_dict")."""
try:
    # tag_lookup = trn_dict[old_tag]
    # trans = maketrans(old_tag, tag_lookup)
    trans = maketrans(old_tag, trn_dict[old_tag])  # Just did the above two lines on one line
except KeyError:
    print("Error in file {}! The tag {} wasn't found in the translation table. "
          "Make sure the translation table is up to date. "
          "The program will continue with the rest of the file, but this tag will be skipped!".format(f_in,
                                                                                                      old_tag))
    return None
new_tag = old_tag.translate(trans)
return new_tag
```

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/ANCv28nF) my translation table. It's a tab-delimited text file, and the old tag is column 1, and the new tag is column 2. I translate from old tag to new tag.

The strange this is that it converts just fine for some tags. For example, "P010" gets translated correctly. What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `maketrans`, as it works on *individual characters* (per [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)). Make it a dictionary, with your original text (1st column) as the key and the new text (2nd column) as its value.

Then you can look up any tag `x` with `trn_dict[x]`, wrapped by a `try` or with a test beforehand `if x in trn_dict`.

```
database = """P001  AAAA
P002    AAAT
P003    AAAG
P004    AAAC
P005    AATA
P006    AATT
P007    AATG
P008    AATC
P009    ATAA
P010    ATAT
P011    ATAG
P012    ATAC
P013    ATTA
P014    ATTT
P015    ATTG
P016    ATTC
P017    AGAA
P018    AGAT
P019    AGAG
P020    AGAC
P021    AGTA
P022    AGTT
P023    AGTG
P024    AGTC
""".splitlines()

trn_dict = {str.split()[0]:str.split()[1] for str in database}

def translate_tag(old_tag, trn_dict):
    """Function to convert any old tags to their new format based on the translation dictionary (variable "trn_dict")."""
    try:
        return trn_dict[old_tag]
    except KeyError:
        print("Error in file {}! The tag {} wasn't found in the translation table. "
              "Make sure the translation table is up to date. "
              "The program will continue with the rest of the file, but this tag will be skipped!")
    return None

print (translate_tag('P020', trn_dict))
```

shows the expected value `AGAC`.

(That string-to-list-to-dict code is a quick hack to get the data in the program and is not really part of this how-to.)

Comment: Well, this turned out to be much easier than I expected! You're right, I could've just looked up the old tag in my dictionary and returned its corresponding new tag...

Thanks for your help!